# Using Modernizr on an existing HTML5 application to make it compatible with ie8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I have software that uses html5 and websockets and allows me to create a webpage that allows users to connect to a windows server using remote desktop protocol in their web browser, can I use modernizer to make this site compatible with ie8? Their are pages that I have to store on the windows server and on my web hosting account that are needed for this app. Basically, can modernizer work on a web app that is already built in html5? If so, how would I do that? 
The software we use is [Ericom AccessNow](http://www.ericom.com/html5_rdp_client.asp?URL_ID=2185&gclid=CIjSnZz438MCFQyEaQodF4kAdw)
Here is a brief description, "Ericom AccessNow is the market's first high performance HTML5 RDP Client, providing browser access to Windows applications and desktops (virtual & physical), running on Windows Terminal Services / RDS / VDI platforms, including Microsoft Hyper-V and other hypervisors. Now supports Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012."
We are using windows Server R2. 
Another important piece of information is that the users can not download another browser or connect from their desktop using the standard rdp connection. Everything has to be done in their browser which is ie8. 
(The solutions works perfectly for html5 capable browsers).

Comment: Modenizr is feature detection, it doesn't add missing features. That said you could detect that the browser doesn't support web sockets and then load a polyfill library. Please refer to the Modenizer documentation regarding polyfills [here](http://modernizr.com/docs/#polyfills), web sockets polyfills can be found [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#web-sockets). This may be a bit of trial and error though, as without knowing the source code of Eircom AccessNow, are you sure its only websockets it needs?

Answer (score 0):

Ericom used to support running AccessNow on IE8 using an opensource plugin called the Chrome Frame plug-in; however, the opensource project is closed and this option is no longer supported. Perhaps this information can help you come up with other ideas though!